# Issue with Python in Maya saying my function isn't defined

Tags: python, maya

So I'm going to be honest, I'm punching a little above my weight here, and I don't fully understand what I'm doing, but as it's been going, I've been learning and making things work, so I'm in the stage where I'm learning valuable lessons on thinking ahead still.  So what I have, is two directories, one with 47 images, and one with 47 directories that have identical names that correspond to the images.  For Example, if there's an image named, "img_05.jpg", then there's also a directory named, "img_05."  The idea is that I made a window that loops through the image directory, and creates an image_icon button for each image, as per this code below:

```
from maya import cmds
import os
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.mel as mel

imagePath = \
    'C:/IMAGES/_ICONS_/'
if cmds.window('window1', q=1, ex=1):
    cmds.deleteUI('window1')
cmds.window('window1', t='SCAN IMPORTER', mb=1)
cmds.gridLayout(cw=150, w=500, nc=8, h=800, ch=150)

getImgList = os.listdir(imagePath)

# print getImgList

i = 0
for i in getImgList:
    ImgNamStr = i
    ImgNamNum1 = ImgNamStr.split('.')

    # print ImgNamNum1[0]

    scanBtn = cmds.iconTextButton(i=imagePath + i, c='scanImp("' + i
                                  + '")', dcc='scan_light("' + i
                                  + '")')

cmds.showWindow('window1')
```

I have my other functions defined as such,

```
def scanImp(*args):
    print args[0] + ' ' + ' was pushed.'
    ImgNmNoExt = args[0].split('.')

  # print ImgNmNoExt[0]

    ScanBtnPath = imagePath + ImgNmNoExt[0]
    print 'the directory is:' + ' ' + ScanBtnPath
```

And when I run this through the maya script editor, it works all as expected.  However, when I source it through a shelf button, (the script directory is added to the path at startup) I get an error saying that scanImp isn't defined.  Am I missing something really obvious here?

*edited to fix name of function

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your error message and code differs because there is no function called `scanBusImp()`. Beside this error, the main problem lies in the way the UI works in Maya. You can try:

```
    scanBtn = cmds.iconTextButton(i=imagePath + i, c='import scanimporter; scanimporter.scanBusImp("' + i
                              + '")', dcc='scan_light("' + i
                              + '")')
```

To make it work. `scanimporter` is the name I gave the script file. For this reason I recommend to use classes to work with UI's and callbacks, makes it easier to work with. If you use a class, you can just call the method like this:

```
def scanBusImp(self, *args):
    importSomething

def createUI(self):
    self.scanBtn = cmds.iconTextButton(i=imgpath..., c=self.scanBusImp)
```

Comment: So, I actually just made a typo in changing up some names when I posted it here to make it easier to read, so that's not the issue for sure, (thank you for catching that for these purposes though) My question stands then about classes, I need to read up on that, but would the fact that it doesn't have a class account for the fact that it's not recognizing the function?

Comment: If you do not have a class and access its members, you will need a global function. That's the reason why I added `import scanimporter`to the command in the first example. Without it the window ui simply does not see this function.

Comment: I completely misunderstood that part of the post, wow I feel stupid haha, Well thank you very much, that absolutely solved the issue I was having.  Thank you!